# How to do String Reverse,count length in C++ or C?

Tags: c++, c, string

How to do Reverse String & count length of string in C or C++ **without using any library function**??

Comment: You should do your homework by yourself.

Comment: you should not asked for direct solution without trying your own

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not display any effort from OP's side till time. [On-topic Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: Also, `C` ___or___ `C++`, choose one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

```
char str[100], temp;
       int i, j = 0;

       printf("\nEnter the string :");
       gets(str);

       i = 0;
       j = strlen(str) - 1;

       while (i < j) {
          temp = str[i];
          str[i] = str[j];
          str[j] = temp;
          i++;
          j--;
       }

       printf("\nReverse string is :%s", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

 char a[20],a1[20];
 int i,j,count=0;
 cout<<"Enter any String:"<<"\n";
 gets(a);    cout<<"Reverse of the string is: ";

  for(i=1;a[i]!='\0';++i);
 for(j=i-1;j>=0;--j)
 {cout<<a[j];count++;}
 cout << "\nLength: " << count;return 0;
}
```

Comment: if u dont want to use gets() , then use while(cin.get() != '\n') something like that .